# What's the meaning of my work contract?

Tags: salary, contracts

I have been invited to work abroad in a restaurant as a Sushi chef for two years. There's a list of benefits that I will get if I work there. Here's some of the list:

- Every Two Year One month Salary (total $1400)
- Every Two Year Two Month Vacations
- Every Two Year One Ticket (home country - workplace - home country)

My questions are:

1. What's the meaning of point one? Am I paid $1400 for two years? That means $58 a month?
2. What's the meaning of point two? Do I get a vacation / day off for two months (60 days) for two years of working?
3. In point three, do I only get one ticket for two years?
4. Are these benefits normal? Should I sign the contract?

Comment: Why not ask the company for clarification?

Comment: I'm afraid I lost the contract if I ask the company too much. Sorry

Comment: You will not lose the contract asking for clarification.

Comment: Seems to me like accepting an offer that you can't live on because you didn't understand the details is a much more dangerous risk than losing the job. This is just something you'll have to ask the company.

Comment: This could be a translation issue. They may be offering a two year contract with monthly pay and other benefits. Ask for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly, please get a lawyer or an experienced person to go through the contract before you take a decision.**

> 1 What's the meaning of point one? Am I paid $1400 for two years? That's mean $58 a month???

**No**. After every two years of service, you get a bonus of one month salary.

> 2 What's the meaning of point two? Do I get a vacation / day off for
>   two months (60 days) for two years working?

**Yes.** *After two years of service

> 3 In point three, Am I only get one ticket for two years?

**Yes**. It means that you get a company-sponsored ticket after two years of service.

> 4 Is that benefits normal?

Yes. They are.

> Should I sign the contract?

That's for you to decide, once you are clear with the details of the contract.

Comment: so, I get $1400 a month. and after 2 years of service I got $1400 as bonus (not monthly salary) ?

Comment: @KissMe Yes. Generally companies give 1 month salary as bonus after every 1 (or) 2 years of service.

Comment: Umm.. my contract is not stated my salary in a month for two years. Is it $1400 a month?

Comment: @KissMe **You need to get a lawyer to go through your contract** :)

Comment: Should I upload my contract? I can't afford lawyer yet so I ask experienced workers and professionals. I am fresh graduated.

Comment: Not a good idea trying to get legal advice from a bunch of strangers on the internet

Comment: Ok. Maybe I'll try contack the company. Thanks for your answer. Have a nice day

Comment: @Dawny33 You don't need a lawyer for EVERYTHING. People on this site are way too quick to recommend it.

Comment: If you have a *specific* question about a part of your contract, you can ask on http://law.stackexchange.com/ . Be sure to quote the exact words from the contract, and explain what exactly you don't understand. Also, include the jurisdiction of the contract (country where it was made).

Comment: "my contract is not stated my salary " - do you mean that the contract does not mention a monthly salary? That would be very unusual. By all means, ask about that if it is not clear to you - or even better, consult someone who can help. Ideally a lawyer, but if that's impractical for you, ask some worker's assistance organisation, trade union or just a friend with life experience.